# Using "AS score" to return relevance score from mysql fulltext search

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, relevance

I'm selecting text from a full-text mysql dbTable,  hits are returned ordered by relevance multiplied by a client supplied weight.  The query works fine, though I'd like to as an 
"AS score" clause to the query to return the actual weighted relevance scores back to the client (via php). I've tried inserting the AS clause everywhere, with no success.
Suggestions?
Thank You

```
$sql1="SELECT * FROM $dbTable 
WHERE MATCH (data) AGAINST ('".$key_word_1."') 
   OR MATCH (data) AGAINST('".$key_word_2."') 
ORDER BY (MATCH (data) AGAINST('".$key_word_1."') * $weight_1) + (MATCH (data) AGAINST('".$key_word_2."') * $weight_2)  DESC 
LIMIT 200";
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
SELECT * , (MATCH (data) AGAINST('".$key_word_1."') * $weight_1) + (MATCH (data) AGAINST('".$key_word_2."') * $weight_2) AS score
....
ORDER BY score DESC
```